# Form submission with php after js validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to submit my form to a PHP file called regier.php after validating it using JavaScript. The HTML form is given below:

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="register.php" method="post" class="sign-up-form">

<div class="input-field">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="username" id="username" onkeyup="validateName()"
   <span id="name-error"></span>
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"      onkeyup="validatePassw()" />
   <span id="passw-error"></span>
</div>

<input onclick="return validateForm()" type="submit" class="btn" value="Registrati">
```

**JAVASCRIPT VALIDATION:**
The following is the JavaScript validation code:

````
function validateForm() {
    if (!validateName()) {
        validateName()
    }
    if (!validateEmail()) {
        validateEmail()
    }
    if (!validatePassw()) {
        validatePassw()
    }
}```
````

Comment: Your action="register.php" will bypass the validate, you want the validateForm() function to call register.php

you will probably have to validate with php

Answer (score 0):

Set the `action` attribute to a file/code to validate the form:

```php
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Comment: where i need to use this action because my form already have one
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="register.php" method="post" class="sign-up-form">

Comment: did you have the `register.php` file?

Comment: yes, i have register.php file

Comment: are you still here?

Comment: yes how can i help you?

Comment: about the answer you gave me, where i need to implement it

Comment: in your php file where you submit the form

Comment: but i have another action: action="register.php"